# phpstorm пропал пункт "create new project from existing files"

Tags: php, битрикс, phpstorm

Сразу оговорюсь, я джавист, и с php и, тем паче, bitrix практически не знаком, но по обстоятельствам, нужно срочно освоить данные технологии, хотя бы в простейшем приближении.

Я пишу в intellij idea и поэтому установил для php - phpstorm, но когда установил пакет битрикс, то пропал пункт (см. картинку) в меню создания проекта phpstorm "create new project from existing files". Поиск в google ни к чему не привел, а переустанавливать phpstorm пока не охота, вдруг дело не в этом.

За сим, вопрос, можно ли как-то реанимировать этот пункт в phpstorm?
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что за плагин ставили - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7616-bitrix-framework-support, или https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8156-bitrixlangcompletion? возможно, плагин не совместим с вашей версией. и каким-то образом блокирует remote hosts плагин? я бы советовала обратиться в тех поддержку, предоставив idea.log

Comment: @lena Вообще-то я никакой плагин не устанавливал, а установил сам Битрикс. Вот - https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/start_encode_php5.zip

Comment: Выберите просто создать новый проект и укажите каталог с файлами, шторм проверит если каталог не пуст выдаст сообщение об этом и спросит требуется ли создать проект на основе существующего кода.

Comment: Просто выберите Open ...

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff тогда вряд ли это как-то связано с Битрикс. проверьте, включен ли плагин remote host access в settings | plugins. если да - см мой комментарий выше. а вообще можно просто использовать File | Open для создания проекта - просто выберите директорию, в которой лежат ваши файлы.